# Does the element $x^2$ have an inverse in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3-x^2-x+1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

In the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3-x^2-x+1)$, does the element $x^2$ have an inverse? How do I answer such a question? I know how to compute the inverse if it exists, and using the same method in this case gives me $[x^2]^{-1} = x^2$, but I don't know how to tell if that is an inverse or not.

I know that an element multiplied by its inverse should yield the identity element, but I'm not sure what the identity element in these situations is. What I know is that an identity element leaves the other elements unchanged, so in $\mathbb{Z}$, that would be $1$. My intuition tells me $x^2$ does not leave every element in $R$ unchanged, but I don't know how to show that.

Comment: The identity element is always preserved under a non-trivial field homomorphism $f$ because $f(1) = f(1 \bullet 1) = f(1) \circ f(1)$ and then dividing by $f(1)$ on both sides yields the answer. This is valid since $f(1) \ne 0$ otherwise $f(x) = f(x \bullet 1) = f(x) \circ f(1) = 0$ for any $x$ in the original field.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Mind over matter

Over the field of two elements, $x^3-x^2-x+1=(x+1)^3$. Thus $R$ is a local ring with a unique maximal ideal $(x+1)$, and everything in that ideal is clearly nilpotent.

In such a ring, each element is either a unit or a nilpotent element.

Now if $x^2$ were nilpotent, $x$ would be nilpotent, just as $x+1$ is. But then $x+1-x=1$ would be in the nilradical, and that is an absurdity.

Therefore $x$ and $x^2$ are units.

### Brute force

If necessary, manual computation yields the answer very quickly as well.

Solving $(ax^2+bx+c)x^2=1$ gets you $a=1$ and $b=c=0$. Double checking, sure enough:

$x^2x^2=x(x^3)=x(x^2+x-1)=x^3+x^2-x=(x^2+x-1)+x^2-x=1$

All computations are done in the quotient, of course.

### Brute finesse

If you get lucky, you can notice that $x^4-1=(x-1)^4$ by the "Freshman dream theorem".  Then $(x-1)^4=0$ since $(x-1)^3=0$, and both chains of equalities together yield $x^4-1=0$, so $x^4=1$ and $x^2$ is a unit.

### Or

From $x^3-x^2-x+1=0$ compute $-1=x^3-x^2-x=x(x^2-x-1)$, so $x$ is a unit, so $x^2$ is a unit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there some other way to see this, because we have not begun talking about Artinial rings yet? :)

Comment: @vincefontaine Well, being Artinian turns out not to matter... gonna make a change to that effect.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the edit!

Comment: @vincefontaine No, my fault, I didn't see your comment until lately :)

Comment: "brute finesse", or is it "elegant whacking"? =)

Comment: @user21820 "Brute finesse" and "elegant hack" are both pretty good oxymorons :)

Comment: I love it how your answer keeps growing. :) I would need some help when it comes to doing computations in the quotient, such as in row three in the Brute Force section (where e.g. $x(x^3) = x(x^2 + x - 1)$ etc.) I'm not sure I fully understand it...

Comment: @vincefontaine in the quotient, "$x^3-x^2-x+1=0$", and therefore $x^3=x^2+x-1$. And, of course, if it wasn't clear earlier, plusses and minuses don't matter since we're working over the field of characteristic 2.

Comment: Of course, now I get it!

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$x^3-x^2 -x =-1$ so $x(x^2 -x-1) =-1$, $x^{-1} = -(x^2 -x-1)$ and $(x^2)^{-1}= (x^{-1})^2 =( x^2 -x-1)^2$. Divide this by $x^3 - x^2 - x +1$ with remainder  and get $-x^2 + 2$ being the inverse of $x^2$.  If the characteristic is $2$ this also equals $x^2$.

Obs: If $x$ satisfies a polynomial equation with invertible constant term then $x$ ( and so all its powers)  is invertible.

Comment: Yup that's a very good observation to remember, though perhaps it's less ambiguous to say "invertible constant term".

Comment: @user21820: Thanks, I changed to "constant".